# jQuery getScript. How to execute a function after it loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have this code inside `http://www.mysite.local/js/site/functions.js`:

```
$.getScript('/js/common/jquery.jsonrpc.js',
            $.jsonRPC.setup({
                        endPoint: '/api/accounts',
                        namespace: 'mynamespace'
                    })
    );
```

It's supposed to run `setup` method of jsonRPC plugin when it loads. But I receive error:

```
$.jsonRPC is undefined
http://www.mysite.local/js/site/functions.js
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$.getScript('/js/common/jquery.jsonrpc.js', function() {
         $.jsonRPC.setup({
                        endPoint: '/api/accounts',
                        namespace: 'mynamespace'
                    });
         }
    );
```

You need to wrap any callbacks with function () { }.