# Loading LessCSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, less

I am loading [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) from Google Code with [jQuery](http://jquery.org/), and want to access [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/)' `Parser()` object by using `less.Parser`.

I can make this load [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) w/ [jQuery](http://jquery.org/) by hacking in a `<link rel>` tag in `<head>`; however that loads `style.less` twice.  I would rather load `style.less` and use `toCSS` to insert it dynamically.  Doing so seems to require calling `less.Parser`.

Currently the code below will not insert css; I think it's because I am not using the right namespace for the `Parser` class.

How can I dynamically load [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) with [jQuery](http://jquery.org/)?

---

**Original code for question**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" id="less_hack">
    // Load LessCSS javascript
    var less_file="/style.less";
    $(function() {
        var css="";
        $.getScript("toCSS.js")
        $.getScript("http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.3.0.min.js",function(){
          $.get(less_file,function(data){
            new(less.Parser)().parse(data,function(e,tree){
              css = tree.toCSS();
            });
          });
        });
    });
    // $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="'+less_file+'">');
</script>
```

I am much more fluent in Python than JavaScript; apologies in advance if I have somehow missed a basic js concept.

---

**Modified code after Patrick's answer**

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load LessCSS javascript
    var less_file="http://www.mysite.local/style.less";
    $(function() {
        var css="";
        $.getScript("http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.3.0.min.js",function(){
          $.get(less_file,function(data){
            var parser = new(less.Parser);
            parser.parse(data, function (err, tree) {
                if (err) { return console.error(err) }
                css = tree.toCSS();
                // Insert rendered css inline
                $("<style/>").html(css).appendTo("body");
            });
          });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have namespaces...

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829681/667301).  What does that namespace belong to?

Comment: @arxanas it's misleading to say "javascript doesn't have namespaces." Everyone calls the concept of putting things under a single object "namespacing" in javascript. You are techically correct but just saying "javascript doesn't have namespaces" will only confuse people.

Comment: I am doing the same thing on my app.  Did you ever figure out how to resolve relative URLs for background images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

I think the problem was that you were calling Parser as a function, instead of an object `new(less.Parser)()`.

Modify your code to this:

```
var less_file="/style.less";
$(function() {
    var css="";
    $.getScript("http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.3.0.min.js",function(){
      $.get(less_file,function(data){
        var parser = new(less.Parser);
        parser.parse(data, function (err, t) {
            if (err) { return console.error(err) }
            css = t.toCSS();
            $("<style/>").html(css).appendTo("body");
        });            
      });
    });
});
```

See a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/E6hsC/

Comment: Hmmm... after adding that to my code, firebug throws `less.Parser is not a constructor`

Comment: What are you trying to change the namespace to?

Comment: I want `less-1.3.0.min.js` to be accessed through `less`; my hope is that `less.Parser` would get the `Parser` object from the aforementioned file

Comment: What do you see when you put `if (e) { return console.error(e) }` above `css = tree.toCSS()` on your original code?

Comment: If you want it to apply the css, add `$("<style/>").html(css).appendTo("body");` after `css = t.toCSS()`.